Database.Upsert and (External ID) Wont Upsert
I have a script that does an upsert on Contacts based off of a unique external ID. I am confused why I am getting duplicate errors as the failure response. I know this record already exists in the DB, I want to update it (mapped to the External_Record_No__c). What am I missing?



        Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(contactsToUpsert, Contact.External_Record_No__c, false);
        for (Integer i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            Database.UpsertResult result = results[i];
            Database.Error[] errors = result.getErrors();
            for (Database.Error error : errors) {
                System.debug('Error: ' + error.getMessage());
                System.debug('Status Code: ' + error.getStatusCode());
                System.debug('Field(s) involved: ' + error.getFields());
            }
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Contact failedContact = contactsToUpsert[i];
                system.debug('Account Contact failed to insert: ' + failedContact);
            } else {
                system.debug('Account Contact was successful. ');
            }
        }


Your external ID field allows dupes.

I thought that as well but I double checked and it's marked as unique (I will update post with screenshot)

Running a quick test with a unique external ID field - if external ID conflicts, status_code is DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ID. It comes back with DUPLICATE_VALUE if there's more than one item in the list (contactsToUpsert in your case) with the same external id

Your screenshots appear to include three different external id fields. Are there actually three different external id fields with a uniqueness constraint on them on the Contact object? External_Customer_Id__c External_Record_No__c External_Contact_Id__c

ty to both of you - i got it resolved

Resolved! The issue was three contacts on one Account that all had the same record ID but one was a billing contact, one was a shipping contact, and one was a primary contact. When attempting to insert the contact list, all three were trying to upsert so the system didn't know which one to upsert first. I had a bug in the code, I needed to update the external record no to handle each of these three contact types.
